# Java JDBC connection through a SOCKS Proxy, works on Windows, not on Linux

Tags: java, jdbc, proxy, socks

A Java application is explicitly setting the SOCKS proxy as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", PROXY_HOST);
    System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", PROXY_PORT);
```

It then connects to a SQL Server using JDBC, and also makes HTTP connections

When the application is run on Windows, the SOCKS proxy is used (i.e. the traffic is visible on the SOCKS proxy logs).

When the application is run on Linux, the SOCKS proxy is used for the HTTP connection, but not the JDBC connection, and the application attempts a direct connection to the SQL Server on port 1433.

Is there any way to force/ensure the application uses the SOCKS proxy for JDBC?

Comment: Possibly related to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/462).

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, will look into the JDBC driver, see if there is an alternative.